# How to show large icon in notification

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

[image]

There is a small icon and a large icon in the attached image of a notification. I would like to create a similar notification. I am able to set the small icon using `NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon()`. But I am not able to set the large icon. Can anyone please help me with this.

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.ic_notification_icon))
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.ic_notification_icon))
                .bigLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)))
            .setColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setContentText(notificationText)
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0, 400, 250, 400))
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    Intent(context, SplashActivity::class.java),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )
            )
```

I tried adding the large icon using the above code, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

1st way(this is what you want)

```
.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory. decodeResource (resources , R.drawable. ic_launcher_foreground ))
```

2st way

```
.setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(aBitmap)
                .bigLargeIcon(null))
```

Comment: I have updated the question with my code. I tried using both of your approaches but somehow they are not working.

Comment: The issue was with the icon that I was using, I am not sure why svg was not working. Changing it to png did the trick for me.

Comment: i have the same problem, svg didn't work for me either. I haven't tried making png though. does png work

Answer (score 1):

We can convert svg to bitmap images and set it to notification icons.

```
fun getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(context: Context?, drawableId: Int): Bitmap {
            val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, drawableId)
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                drawable!!.intrinsicWidth,
                drawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            drawable.draw(canvas)
            return bitmap
        }
```

Comment: The only thing that worked for me